# Android Studio 3.0 parameter hints information not always visible?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Sorry, I don't know how this new functionality is called exactly, please look at screenshot:
[image]

So, parameter name is visible in method call. This is cool, but as you can see, only first parameter in this case, second has no name visible. From my observations, it sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't and I am unable to figure out why.

Can I configure it, or it's just a bug? Or maybe I'm not understand how that functionality is intended to work.

Comment: when you send static input to method  then shows parameter name .

Comment: by default, android studio doesn't show if method name contains parameter name and for builders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable it by doing the following:

1. Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > **Show parameter name hints**
2. Click **Configure**
3. Language: -> **Java**
4. Options -> Check **Show hints even when type of expression is clear**

As you can see below, it is visible for all parameters regardless of type:

[image: parameter hind is visible for all parameters regardless of type]

**EDIT**

It looks like this setting was removed in Android Studio 4.0

There are however new **Inlay Hints** options:

1. Go to File > Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > Java > **Parameter hints**
2. Check **Show parameter hints for:**

[image]

Answer (score 20):

**1.**

Press Alt-Enter on your method and select doesn't show hints for the current method.
Then you can see a dialog in the bottom right of the android studio. 
select Show Parameters Hint Setting, now you can customize this functionality. and finally, select undo in the dialog.

**2.**

File -> Setting -> Editor -> General -> Appearaance-> show parameters hint configure

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio 4.1.3

`File` - `settings` - `Editor` - `inlay hints` - `Kotlin` (or java) - choose "types" then mark (or unmark) the box that says "show hints for" then mark (or unmark) your choices

[image: How its made in Android Studio 4.1.3]

Answer (score 3):

## In 2020

**For Webstorm & PhpStorm**

If variable calling not shows the parameter hints, you can enable it by going to

> File => Setting => Editor => Inlay Hints => (preferred language) => parameter hints => `For non-literal arguments`

Comment: This setting under Java. Also, disappointingly, it appears there's no way to configure parameter hints to always appear.

Comment: The Question was about Android Studio. I don't understand why someone should be interested in solutions for other IDEs that are not even meant for Android development...

Comment: This answer exists here because if someone searching for JetBrains specific problem, he/she can found the answer from this post

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio Flamingo or Higher**

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> [Explore Options]**

Answer (score 0):

Only the primitive and some complex types show hints. You can disable it by right clicking on hint and then "Disable Hints".

For example:

```
public void myFunction(int a, boolean b, MyClass myClass)
    //do something
}
```

If you call:

```
myFunction(10, true, new MyClass());
```

Only the first two will show hints...

Comment: I don't want to disable, I want to get hints for all parameters. I know I can disable or configure in Settings->Appearance. But still it's not always showing

Comment: Actually, the hints will show only for primitive types, like int or boolean. If the parameter is a class you created for example, the hints will not show.

Comment: yes it seems you are right. I still don't undestand reason why my question is down voted though :/ It;s not obvious only primitives are supported

Comment: EDIT: nope, some complex types are supported as well, for example `Context`: https://i.imgur.com/Jzj3aCL.png

Comment: The hints show for literals, not primitives. Variables with primitive types as arguments do not trigger hints, presumably because variable names ought to be self-documenting. Literal strings, booleans, numerics, `null` and `this` all trigger hints.