# How to show parameters hints in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a shortcut to trigger the parameters hints in Android Studio as it shows in the following photo:

[image]

Comment: Not the right place to ask this over here, you can ask about programming errors & stuff. You can easily do that after some google time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reveal the `Parameter Info`, place the cursor in the parameters' location within a method, constructor, etc and:

On Mac, use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

On Windows use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Good but seems like a temporary solution.
To fully enable the SHOW HINTS feature, read this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136404/android-studio-3-0-parameter-hints-information-not-always-visible