# Android Studio 4 Parameter hints not always showing

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically, [this very same question except for Android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136404/android-studio-3-0-parameter-hints-information-not-always-visible). The options listed in that answer do not exist anymore, but I'd really like to be able to see these, like you can in swift.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want `Enable parameter hints` - do Ctrl+Shift+A (or the equivalent) and start typing "parameter", it'll pop up

Comment: That doesn't do anything